# Изберком или избирком?

Tags: орфография

Здравствуйте!
Завис над словом "избе(и)рком". С одной стороны, это сокращение от "избИрательный комитет", а с другой, если применять к этом слову правила русского языка, то по причине отсутствия А после корня, надо писать "изберком". А как все-таки правильно?
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, Вы правильно рассуждаете. Это сложносокращенное слово от словосочетания "избирательный комитет". При этом исходное слово, от которого взята сокращенная часть, не меняется